# Google Analytics ecommerce implementation

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce

I don't know why Google Analytics is not reading my code. I don't know where it is my mistake.
the code that is generate when I do a transaction is this:

```js
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '195',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Company name',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '18.00',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '0.00',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '3.12',                     // Tax.
  'currency': 'EUR'
});


 ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
   'id': '761',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
   'name': 'Agus y los monstruos 3. La canción del parque ESP.',    // Product name. Required.
   'sku': 'xxxxx',                 // SKU/code.
   'category': 'Primeres novel·les',         // Category or variation.
   'price': '9.00',                 // Unit price.
   'quantity': '2'                   // Quantity.
 });

    
ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I write this in the header. I don't know if something is missing or if I should load a library previously.

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable enhanced e-commerce in the GA admin settings?

Comment: No, I didn't. I enable only the simple one.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought you were using enhanced ecommerce. What leads you to believe that there is a problem? Is there an error message somewhere or is data  not showing up after 48 hours, or ??

Comment: 48 hours? I thought it was immediately. I buy something and it does not appear in the analytics.

Comment: You need to wait up to 48 hours for data to be processed, but typically you should see updates in even as short as 5 hours (depending on the amount of configuration in GA). You can use GA Debugger (Chrome addon) to immediately see if your hits go through to GA though.

Comment: 24hours later, it continues without appearing anything in the GA

Comment: I am stupid, I had the tracker blocker enabled. This code up works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine although the ID in Item and transaction should be the same.
Have you enabled [ecommerce tracking in google analytics](http://marketlytics.com/analytics-faq/enable-ecommerce-tracking-google-analytics).
Do you see any errors in the console?

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.

Comment: I had the tracker blocker enabled. Thanks. I'm so stupid